# Focusing on <input type=number> in Android browser the page scrolls to the bottom

Tags: android, input, webview, focus, android-webview

I am viewing a webpage in Android browser.

When I focus(tap) on `<input type='number'>` the page scrolls to the bottom

Is it a bug and how to solve it?

Comment: The `View` tends to scroll to let the input field visible above the keyboard. Is that the behavior you are describing? If not, post some code!

Comment: @shkschneider, edited the post - I'm vieweing the web-page in Android browser.

Comment: You did not answer my question: is the behavior I'm describing what happens? Because if so, it's not a bug, it's allowing you to see both input and keyboard at the same time.

Comment: @shkschneider, yes it is, but what i get is the field is not in the visible area. Other fields with type='text' work fine.

Comment: We need your code to help you debug this...